# Simple View Won't Update with Aurelia When Converting Object to Map

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I created a gist to illustrate my issue:

https://gist.run/?id=8d03b3b8f8deef92e3a9

**Relevant ViewModel:**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import obj from 'otherModule';

@inject(obj)
export class Example {

  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.index = Object.keys(obj).length;
  }

  addAnother() {
    this.obj[ this.index ] = `test${this.index}`;
    this.index++;
  }
}
```

**View**:

```
<template>
  <require from="./asMap.js"></require>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="[key, value] of obj | asMap">${value}</li>
  </ul>

  <button click.trigger="addAnother()">Add to Object</button>
</template>
```

The summary of my issue involves trying to display contents from a simple object in a view. I wanted to use Aurelia's `repeat` operator in the view, and also use the Map() syntax to do so (ex. `repeat.for="[key, value] of object"`). For this reason I'm converting the object to a Map via a valueConvert module:

```
export class asMapValueConverter {
    toView(object) {
        return Object.keys(object).reduce((map, current) => {
            map.set(current, object[ current ]);
            return map;
        }, new Map());
    }

}
```

This works to display the data as the view initializes, but if the object is updated in the ViewModel, then it is NOT updated in the view.

At this point if I navigate to a different view and return, it will then display the added elements. As far as I can tell there is not a way to update the view without navigating to another one and returning.

Is this a bug? Am I just doing something horrible? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/356

Here's an option for you.  It will only work if all your object's props are defined ahead of time:
https://gist.run/?id=b9071aaa4447426a0570

The only other way would be to use dirty-checking because there's no other way to tell when a property is added/removed from an object without Object.observe.